# How many people live in a silo?

Tags: wool

I don't know if it has ever been mentioned or estimated at least, considering the few descriptions we have.

Do we know how many people live in a silo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Shift:

> The original project Donald designs called for *"a bunker that could house ten thousand people for a year"*. Later in the same book, there is concern when Silo 32 gets *"close to the maximum"*: *"Silo thirty-two had crept above nine thousand inhabitants"*.

It also refers to the initial population:

> *"There were four thousand names in that first generation of silo two. Four thousand exactly. Roughly half were female."* (For a specific silo, but let's assume that this was typical.)

In Dust:

> It seems that the population of Silo 18 is around five thousand: *"'So, we're under five thousand residents for the first time in thirty years,' Marsha said"*.

This suggests that the normal population is **somewhere around four or five thousand**, with a maximum of ten thousand.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.hughhowey.com/the-next-wool-book/#comment-817) entry from http://www.hughhowey.com:

> which is why, when pressed, I give 5,000 as the maximum population of a silo

Obviously this number (dating from February 5, 2012) has aged. It *does* nicely illustrate the crowded living conditions the population has to endure.